# Bash split a list of files

Tags: bash, shell-script, split

I have 200 files in a folder like: `test_1_cfg.dat`, `test_2_cfg.dat`,.... and so on. I need to include in a bash script the first 40 files as input and run some process, another script to read the next 40 files and run another process.

So I was thinking of a way to have a list of the names of the files and then just split that list but I'm not sure how to do it in bash.

Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Method #1 - Using head & tail

You can use the command `head` to pull out the first 40 files from a file listing like so:

```
$ head -40 input_files | xargs ...
```

To get the next 40:

```
$ tail -n +41 input_file  | head -40 | xargs ...

...

$ tail -n +161 input_file | head -40 | xargs ...
```

You can keep walking down the list, 40 at a time using this same technique.

#### Method #2 - Using xargs

If you happen to have all your filenames in a variable, you can use `xargs` like so to break up the list into chunks of X number of elements.

#### Example

Pretend my files are called 1-200. So I load them up into a variable like so:

```
$ files=$(seq 200)
```

You can see the first couple of items in this variable:

```
$ echo $files  | head -c 20
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now we use `xargs` to divide it up:

```
$ xargs -n 40 <<<$files
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 ...
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 ...
121 122 123 124 125 ...
141 142 143 144 145 ...
161 162 163 164 165 ...
181 182 183 184 185 ...
```

You could then pass the above command to another `xargs` which would then run your program:

```
$ xargs -n 40 <<<$files | xargs ...
```

If the contents of the list of files isn't easily accessible from a variable you can give `xargs` a list via a file instead:

```
$ xargs -n 40 <input_file
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 ...
81 82 83 84 85 86 87 ...
121 122 123 124 125 ...
141 142 143 144 145 ...
161 162 163 164 165 ...
181 182 183 184 185 ...
```

#### Method #3 - Bash arrays

Say you had your filenames in a Bash array. Again I'm using a sequence of number 1-200 to represent my filenames.

```
$ foo=( $(seq 200) )
```

You can see the contents of the array like so:

```
$ echo ${foo[@]}
1 2 3 4 5 ....
```

Now to get the 1st 40:

```
$ echo "${foo[@]:0:40}"
```

The 2nd 40, etc:

```
$ echo "${foo[@]:40:40}"
...
$ echo "${foo[@]:160:40}"
```

Comment: I really like the xargs acrobatics but bash arrays are also useful. Something to learn here!

Comment: Is there a way to use bash arrays but without knowing before hand how many files have to be split in groups of 40? In other words, given a vector of N elements obtain a list of lists of (at most) 40 elements (the last list will have <= 40 elements)?

Comment: @giuliobullsaver see example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697801/giving-files-in-batches-to-a-script#comment1318735_697802

Answer (score 9):

This is a perfect recipe for `xargs`:

```
cat list_of_files | xargs -n 40 command
```

Quoting from `man xargs`:

```
 -n number   Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input
             for each invocation of the utility.  An invocation of utility
             will use less than number standard input arguments if the
             number of bytes accumulated (see the -s option) exceeds the
             specified size or there are fewer than number arguments
             remaining for the last invocation of utility.  The current
             default value for number is 5000.
```

In order to perform different actions for each set, you'd need to get relevant lines before passing those to `xargs`:

```
 sed -n '1,40p' list_of_files | xargs command1
 sed -n '41,80p' list_of_files | xargs command2
 ...
```

Comment: great!!! Thank you. I can now split the files, but how can I select, for example, the second set of 40 files for the other script?

Comment: @Alejandro Refer to the update.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I LOVE the `xargs -n 40 <<<$files` but since it does "40 args" per line I did

```
threads=10
xargs -n $((40/threads)) <<<$files
```

or if in an array..

```
n=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
xargs -n $((${#n[@]}/threads))

while read -r input; do
  for item in $input; do
    <..stuff..>
  done &
done <<< $(for x in ${n[@]}; do echo $x; done | xargs -n $((${#n[@]}/threads)))
wait
```

Comment: Please try to improve readability by formatting code examples as such (s. https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help - or click the ? in the top/right corner of the editor)