# Giving files in batches to a script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have many files, and the naming convention is as follows:

`file1_d`, `file2_d`, `file3_d`, ..., `fileN_d`

I want to provide the first `k` files into a script as input, then the following `k` files as a second batch, and so on. Is there an easy way to do this in shell-script, such as using arrays for example?

Answer (score 6):

I will be assuming that you want to execute the script multiple times and that you want to provide your files in batches as command-line arguments to the script, one batch at a time each time you run the script. (Another interpretation of your requirements would be that the script reads the files from standard input and that you want to feed it the concatenation of `k` files at a time.  The code below would only need small changes to allow for this interpretation.)

In the `bash` shell, you could use an array that you give to your script in chunks.

To create the array, we could do

```bsh
files=( file*_d )
```

This would expand the globbing pattern `file*_d` and put the resulting names into the array in lexicographic order.  If you need the filenames in numeric order and if your numbers aren't zero-filled, then it would be easier to use a brace expansion:

```bsh
files=( file{1..N}_d )
```

... where `N` is the maximum number (the actual number, not a variable as `bash` does not understand variables in brace expansion ranges).

In the `zsh` shell, you could create the array using

```bsh
files=( file<->_d )
```

... to get them in numerical order.  The code below would work for both the `zsh` and `bash` shells.

You can then call your script in a loop like so:

```bsh
k=10
while [ "${#files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; do
    ./myscript "${files[@]:0:k}"
    files=( "${files[@]:k}" )
done
```

This would call `./myscript` with the `k` first entires of the `files` array, and then remove those entries from the array.  It would continue until the array is empty.

Comment: why not `k=10; for ((i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; i += k)); do ./myscript "${files[@]:i:k}"; done`?

Comment: @Fravadona That's also possible, obviously, if you think that makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

In `zsh`, you'd use `zargs` for that:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -l ${k?} -- file<->_d(n) -- myscript
```

With bash and GNU utilities, you could do something similar with:

```
xargs -r0n"${k?}" -a <(
  shopt -s failglob extglob
  pattern='file+([0123456789])_d' IFS=
  printf '%s\0' $pattern | sort -zV) myscript
```

The `n` glob qualifier or `sort -V` make sure file names are sorted numerically, so that `file10_d` comes after `file9_d` and not in between `file1_d` and `file2_d` for instance.

Both `zargs` and GNU `xargs` have a `-P` option in case you want to run some of those `myscript` invocations in parallel.

Answer (score 4):

You could use GNU parallel to do your batches in parallel.

```
printf '%s\n' file*_d | parallel -j 2 -N "$k" ./myscript
```

If your script doesn't read from stdin but instead expects an argument you could  pass that with `:::` like this:

```
parallel -j 2 -N "$k" ./myscript ::: file*_d
```

`-j` specifies the number of jobs that run simultaneously (default is the number of available cores) and `-N` specifies the argument limit or batch size in your case.  So if you have `-j 2 -N 10` your script will be given a list of 10 files each and two different jobs will run at any time.  As soon as one finishes another will start until all files are consumed.

And if you don't want to run parallel jobs you could just pass `-j 1`

Answer (score 4):

Simple - use `xargs`:

```
$ # Let's create 100 files with your naming convention
$ for i in {1..100} ; do touch $(printf "file%03d_d" $i) ; done

$ # Now let's process them in groups of 4 with this script:
$ cat /path/to/some/script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo called with "$@"

$ ls | LC_ALL=C sort  | xargs -n 4 /path/to/some/script.sh
called with file001_d file002_d file003_d file004_d
called with file005_d file006_d file007_d file008_d
called with file009_d file010_d file011_d file012_d
...
called with file093_d file094_d file095_d file096_d
called with file097_d file098_d file099_d file100_d
```

Using a C-locale prefixed `sort` is probably paranoia on my side - use whatever locale/sort-option that sorts the files in the order you want them to be processed.

And in case you were wondering, this does work properly with numbers that don't divide your dataset perfectly:

```
$ ls | LC_ALL=C sort  | xargs -n 3 /path/to/some/script.sh
...
called with file091_d file092_d file093_d
called with file094_d file095_d file096_d
called with file097_d file098_d file099_d
called with file100_d
```